# MySQL - Display all amounts per month on a given fiscal year

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would to seek some help from the SQL Experts here in Stackoverflow.

I currently have this kind of table:

[image]

And I have been successfully getting the sum amount per year with this query:

```
select case when month(savings_date) >=11
then year(savings_date) +1
else year(savings_date)
end as fiscal, sum(amount)
from net_savings
group by fiscal
```

And having this output:

[image]

[image]

Now I would like to display all the sum amounts per month with a given input of fiscal year. How would I do this?

My fiscal year starts from november and ends at october. So if I have october 2015 in my records, it should not show up when I enter 2016 as fiscal year.

Comment: Your logic says the fiscal year starts in November, not October.

Comment: Your post is not completely visible. The table definition and the output are missing.

Comment: I have modified it a while ago.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
select month(savings_date), sum(amount)
from net_savings
where dateadd(savings_date, interval -2 month)
group by month(savings_date);
```